# I am trying to increment the value of value in count column of the database.i made a logic and it is not working

Tags: php

```
<?php
require 'linking.php';




$query="SELECT `count` FROM `hit_count`";

if(@$query_run=mysqli_query($con,$query))
{
  $count=mysqli_data_seek($query_run,0);
  $fetch=mysqli_fetch_row($query_run);
  $fetch_new=$fetch[0];
        $fetch_row=$fetch_new+1;
  echo $fetch_row;

  $fetch[0]=$fetch_row;
 $update_query="UPDATE `hit_count` SET `count`=$fetch_new";

  if(@$query_new =mysqli_query($update_query))
  {

  echo 'OK';
}
}

?>
```

i am trying to swap the value that i got from the count column with the incremented value so that on 
refresh i get a new value incremented value

Comment: Why are you suppressing messages from the mysqli_query results? That right there could give you the issue.

Comment: Also, why don't you simply issue am "UPDATE `hit_count` SET `count`=`count`+1" ?? And aside from that do a simple select like you do now (although I don't understand why you use so incredible many functions and re-assign variables a 100x just to get 1 value)

Answer (score 6):

If you don't need to actually do anything with the value, running the following query would be faster and more efficient:

```
<?php
require 'linking.php';

$query="UPDATE `hit_count` SET `count`=`count`+1";

if(true === mysqli_query($con,$query))
{
    echo 'OK';
} else
{
    //do something with the error
}
```

Comment: This should be a comment, as it's a suggestion for enhancement, not an answer.

Comment: @Zarathuztra It does answer the question though: "how to increment the value of the count column?"

Comment: it doesn't, see the part of the title where he states the issue: "i made a logic and it is not working". He's not asking for performance enhancements.

Comment: Pointing out flawed logic is fine - though it should be presented as (potentially) working code with an explanation. Race conditions are typical after all.

Comment: @Zarathuztra I've added code to make it a (potentially) working solution. For calculations this simple, doing them client-side (of the sql connection) is asking for trouble. Making the increment on the sql server also protects you from race conditions, as the increment is a single operation, not two

Comment: if i use @T0xicCode method what i will be doing is that i would be incrementing each value in count column rather than a particular value in particular row(which i want to increment)i.e. incrementing just a single value not the whole column.

count=count+1 will increment each value in column count..

Comment: @user18683 You add a `WHERE` clause or a `LIMIT` clause to restrict the number of rows where the increment is made.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the link which is `$con` in your update query, also, don't use `@` with mysqli functions, they supress errors and you wouldn't want that

```
  if($query_new = mysqli_query($con, $update_query))
  {
  echo 'OK';
  }
```

Comment: Why isn't the most correct answer getting more upvotes -_-
Since he isn't passing $con in the update query, it's never going to update in the first place. Never mind any of the performance issues the other answers are pointing out.

Comment: @AD7six What do you mean by you're just guessing? It's obvious. he requires the link in his function which he used in the other query that he did above.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the right variable in your UPDATE

```
$update_query="UPDATE `hit_count` SET `count`=$fetch_new";
```

should be

```
$update_query="UPDATE `hit_count` SET `count`=$fetch_row";
```

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning the incremented value to `$fetch_row` but using `$fetch_new` in the UPDATE query, which still has the old value.

You need to change the line to use `$fetch_row`:

```
$update_query="UPDATE `hit_count` SET `count`=$fetch_row";
```

But instead of doing that, I would recommend looking at T0xicCode's answer as that is likely a more efficient way of doing what you want to do.